# Access to the path 'D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\vivek-vichar.org\....\temp\excelsheets\Student RegistrationTrial2.xls' is denied

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

Here i am uploading Excelsheet which adds data to sql tables.
Code works perfectly on localhost. after hosting it on server its giving me the error, 
**Access to the path 'D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\vivek-vichar.org....\temp\excelsheets\Student RegistrationTrial2.xls' is denied.**

I have created temp\excelsheets directory already.

```
protected void import_xls_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string savePath;
            savePath = Server.MapPath("/temp/excelsheets");

            if (xlsupload.HasFile)
            {
                string fileName = xlsupload.FileName;
                savePath = Path.Combine(savePath, fileName);
                xlsupload.SaveAs(savePath);                  

                string excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + savePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'";

                OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
                excelConnection.Open();

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet2$]", excelConnection);                    
                OleDbDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(SqlConnectionstring.mainConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity);
                if(grouplist.SelectedItem.Text == "A")
                {
                    sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "dbo.studentA"; 
                }
                else if (grouplist.SelectedItem.Text == "B")
                {
                    sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "dbo.studentB";
                }
                else if (grouplist.SelectedItem.Text == "C")
                {
                    sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "dbo.studentC";
                }
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("UserName", "UserName");
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Password", "Password");
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Standard", "Standard");
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Division", "Division");
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("SchoolName", "SchoolName");
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Language", "Language");                                       

                sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);

                lblmsg.Visible = true;
                lblmsg.Text = "Your data uploaded successfully";
                excelConnection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblmsg.Visible = true;
            lblmsg.Text = ex.Message.ToString();

        }
```

**Webconfig**

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="sqlconn" connectionString="Data Source=<servername>;User Id=******;Password=******;persist security info=False;Connect Timeout=0;Max Pool Size=10000" providerName="System.Data.SqlCient" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server, locate the file or folder containing it and :-

- Right-click and select Properties.
- Add the user account your process is running under to the security permissions with read/write access.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string here is for your database.  The 'user' that needs to access the spreadsheet is the user your IIS application is running as, possibly the IUSR account, or the account that your application pool is configured to use depending on the version of IIS and the setup.